# Quick edit on Display form

Tags: list, list-form

All,

I would like to apply a quick edit in for all fields in the display form? Could we do that? For example, I have a Person list. In the display form, I would like to have a pencil icon on the right hand side of each item. When user clicks on that pencil, SharePoint will allow user to modify that field.

Thanks,

Comment: is it for one list or for every list you will ever create?

Comment: It's just for one list only

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Forms in SharePoint Designer or with Infopath

InfoPath:
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.ch/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customize-sharepoint.html
SharePoint Designer http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx

With InfoPath you can create Rules, for example what should happen if you click on the edit icon you want to use (in your case enable the field). Let me know if you need further help.